# How to extract number more gracefully in Python using xpath and regular expression

Tags: python, regex, xpath, scrapy

I have a small html snippet from which I want to extract just a *number* – actually a grade. I am using Python with `scrapy` and `re`.

My code works, but is far from being nice.

Here is the html snippet, from which I just want to get the `2`.

```
<div id="left">
<div class="0"><b>Certificate:</b></div>
<div class="1">
<div></div>
<div>
<a class="link" href="new.html">Maths</a>&nbsp;(First)&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Grade 2<br>
</div>
</div>
<div class="2"></div>
</div>
```

And here is how I solved it so far:

```
! note = sel.xpath('//*[@id="left"]/div[2]/div[2]/text()[2]').extract()
! print note
> [u'\xa0(First)\xa0\xa0\xa0Grade 2']
! note_string = ''.join(note)
! note_only = re.search(r'\d+', note_string).group()
> 2
```

It's certainly not best practice to transform lists to strings to extract such tiny information.

How can I do better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following XPath expression to get the `2`

```
substring-after(//*[@id="left"]/div[2]/div[2]/text(), "Grade ")
```

Comment: Thanks, splendid answer. Actually, to make your answer complete, here is the full command:
`sel.xpath('substring-after(//*[@id="left"]/div[2]/div[2]/text()[2], "Grade ")').extract()`